# How to detect (and possibly auto-merge) git commits from a downstream branch back up to an upstream

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-flow

We use a GitFlow branching strategy where we have a permanent **develop** branch and a permanent **master** branch.  All work is done in temporary **hotfix** or **feature** branches.  We also have release branches, but in the interest of trying to keep this simple, I'll talk in terms of just the two permanent branches.

Whenever a production release issue comes up, we'll branch off **master** and create a **hotfix** branch.  After development and testing is complete, the changes are merged to **master**.  Now in a perfect world, after these changes are merged to **master**, they'd immediately be merged back up to **develop** as well - however people sometimes forget/make mistakes/<insert desired excuse here> and often times it'll be a day or two before we realize that someone forgot to merge their changes back up.

I'm curious how others deal with this scenario as I would think anyone following GitFlow would encounter this from time to time.  I know the obvious response is, well they should be responsible enough to remember to do it... but anytime we're depending on a human to remember to do something, we're just asking for trouble IMO.  I would think it'd be fairly straightforward to script something to possibly run every night and compare **master** to **develop** to check if there are commits that exist in **master** but *not* **develop** (as this should never happen).  At the very least, an email or some type of notification could be sent alerting us to the issue.  Or even taking it a step further, I would think you could potentially even go so far as to actually create the necessary pull request (as we require code reviews prior to merging).

I've searched around on the web and haven't really found anything, so I'm just wondering if maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly.  I would think this would be a fairly common issue, so I'm just surprised I'm not finding scripts or plugins to do this type of thing.  We are starting to try to develop something, I just want to make sure we're not reinventing the wheel or off in left field.

*We do use Azure DevOps for our SDLC by the way.

Any feedback or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT - yes, thank you.  i upvoted your response.  I was hoping I'd get some more feedback from others - it just seems so odd to me that this isn't a common issue for anyone doing GitFlow.  We can definitely script something, and had actually been looking at the APIs you referenced, I'm just surprised no one has developed a devops plugin, written a blogpost, published some powershell scripts, etc.  If nothing else, it seems like a great opportunity for us to do something.

Comment: I've added git-flow tag for your issue. In my opinion, Git branches are inexpensive to create and maintain, you could keep your branch strategy simple. If possible, you could only keep only one high quality, up-to-date main branch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/git-branching-guidance?view=azure-devops.

Answer (score 1):

You could check DevOps REST API to compare branches and create pull requests:

1. Get diffs between branches:

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/diffs/commits?baseVersion={baseVersion}&targetVersion={targetVersion}&api-version=6.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/diffs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#between-branches

2. Create pull requests:

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=6.0`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0